# Scraping Image from Bing

Tags: web-scraping

For some reasons I can only get four images when scraping the following Bing's page: http://www.bing.com/news/search?q=zara&go=Search&qs=bs&form=QBNT

While I can retrieve ten titles or snippets, so my question is why can I only get four images with the code below? Ideally I'd like to get as much images as titles or snippets.

```
<?php

include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.bing.com/news/search?q=zara&go=Search&qs=bs&form=QBNT');

foreach($html->find('.image img') as $element) 

echo $element->src . '<br>';

?>
```

Results:

```
/th?id=ON.62EC487ABAB1647966D6D3700B1F4D83&pid=News&w=150&h=100&c=7&rs=2
/th?id=ON.F34C27652CFA4A316BAA99A43C9D1E9D&pid=News&w=150&h=100&c=7&rs=2
/th?id=ON.B0F8C442159754AF12FFF30E315A5E2F&pid=News&w=150&h=100&c=7&rs=2
/th?id=ON.261655923157551E348AE0085F7E0F9A&pid=News&w=150&h=100&c=7&rs=2
```

Comment: Can you show structure from where You want to scraping data, means html. Sorry I cannot see that I am on phone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kumar. Would that work: view-source:http://www.bing.com/news/search?q=zara&go=Search&qs=bs&form=QBNT I think it's because some images' src are different i.e. some of them content this: src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBTAA7" which doesn't seem to link to any images when clicking on it. Must be some sort of encoding.

Comment: Hey, seb does it work? I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use to scrap data from nwsImg class. Like

```
foreach($html->find("img[class=nwsImg]") as $da)
{
     echo $da->src;
}
```

If it does not work please comment below. I have not tested it.

**Edited:**
I have found it on mobile version of that link which you post in comment section of your question. Yes it is much harder for scraping data from a pc mode. Here is my trick

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php'; 

$opts = array('http' => array( 'header' => 'User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/3B48b Safari/419.3', ) );
 $context = stream_context_create($opts);
 $html = str_get_html(file_get_contents("http://www.bing.com/news/search?q=zara&go=Search&qs=bs&form=QBNT", false, $context));

foreach($html->find("img[class=nwsImg]") as $da)
 { 
echo $da->src; 
}
?>
```

Comment: I have added your code below, but I only get a blank page. Also where did you find that class **nwsImg**. I search trough the source code and can't find it.  `<?php

include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
    
$html = file_get_html('https://www.bing.com/news/search?q=zara&FORM=HDRSC6');
                          

foreach($html->find("img[class=nwsImg]") as $da)
{
     echo $da->srcs;
}
?>`

Comment: Thanks a lot Karma, this is working fine now ;-) I'm not sure exactly why, if you have some time, please provide some explanations for the community. Thanks again!